# Are “tué” and “tu” and “tout” pronounced the same?

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

I'm pretty confused by how to make someone understand I am trying to say *tué*, *tu* or *tout*.

Examples:

> J'ai tué mon ami. (I killed my friend.)
>   Tu es mon ami. (You are my friend.)
>   J'ai tout, mon ami. (I have everything, my friend.)

Please help.

Comment: Watch out, the first should be "J'ai tué mon ami", which is very different. And the second should be "Je t'ai".

Comment: @Joubarc: I suspect that the OP was thinking of some contracted form of "je t'ai eu, mon ami".

Comment: Good news: you'll rarely use the first sentence :)

Comment: Lorsque "J'ai tout mes amis." est prononcé par un italien mafiosi, tu ne peux pas savoir si c'est ça ou "Je tue mes amis." (If I got you confused, ignore the comment, it's a joke)

Comment: « Je trouve ça vraiment triste qu'il se soit _tu_ si jeune. ». In this movie _Nô_ (Lepage, 1998), there's a funny scene about translation (at 1h01:26) where this is translated as _...that he killed himself at such an early age_ until they realize it's rather _that he stopped creating..._. That's one for the books and because _tu_ is a past participle, like _tué_, this makes for a challenge.

Answer (score 15):

Nevertheless `tu`, `tué` and `tout` have all three different pronunciations.

In International Phonetic Alphabet

- `tu` is `/ty/` [Sound](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Fr-tu.ogg)
- `tué` is `/tɥe/` [Sound](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Fr-tuer.ogg)
- `tout` is `/tu/` [Sound](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9f/Fr-tout.ogg)

For the records, sounds are from Wikimédia.

Comment: The sound linked for `tué` is closer to `[tye]`, but indeed, in informal speech, it would be `[tɥe]`.

Comment: @Evpok yes... I know. Can't find a better sample.

Comment: no offence meant, just a clarification for IPA or French learners. Good answer anyway.

Comment: I actually do pronounce "tué" just like in the sample. Can't hear what's wrong with it.

Comment: I believe the other comments are alluding to something I heard somewhere else: not all accents of French turn vowels like /y/, /u/, /i/ into semivowels before inflectional suffixes such as "é." In some accents, "tué," "lié" etc. are two syllables, apparently.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question, "u" and "ou" are pronounced differently in French. However your first two sentences are incorrect, which is probably adding to the difficulty. The first should read *J'ai **tué** mon ami* and it's not totally clear what the second is trying to say.

For a real example of somewhere this can make a difference, note the difference between *Vous lavez-vous?* (Do you wash yourself?) and *Vous l'avez vu?* (Did you see it?) or of course *dessus* and *dessous*, or *cul* and *cou*...

Answer (score 2):

The three are pronounced differently. I don't know the IPA codes, sadly, but you can see the differences there:

- [tue](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/tue)
- [tué](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/tué)
- [tout](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/tout)

You probably pronounce "tout" correctly, but "tu" is a very different sound.